# style label of radio button which is into a div tag

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to make my labels in a different style when the radio button is checked. The problem is that I'm using a javaScript plugin called ezMark which generates

Here is the code.

```
<div class="ez-radio">
    <input type="radio" id="line0" name="line-style" value="1" class="ez-hide">
</div>
<label style="background:url('1.jpg')no-repeat;" ></label>
```

and here is CSS that I tried to use to style the code

```
.ez-radio input:checked+label {...}
```

Honestly I don't need the javaScript on this page, yet I'm using templates and it is dynamically loaded. Is there an option to switch off the ezMark js before the radiobuttons? Or maybe style the label despite the ezMark script.

***EDIT***

The `<div ez-radio` is dynamically generated by the script. I have no control so that I can add the label between this div.

Comment: label should be inside div element, if I'm understanding correctly.

Comment: You're missing a `"` at the end of `class="ez-radio`...

Comment: this was from typing quickly, i'm not missing it, i'll correct that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You elements need to be siblings to use ths `+` selector. CSS can't go "up" the DOM tree, so it will never find the label.

HTML

```
<div class="ez-radio">
    <input type="radio" id="line0" name="line-style" value="1" class="ez-hide">
    <label style="background:url('1.jpg')no-repeat;" >Label</label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ez-radio input[type=radio]:checked + label 
{
    color: #0f0;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_/eCgyH/

---

After your edit about not being able to change the markup, you're going to have to resort to jQuery (javascript library.)

```
$('.ez-radio input[type=radio]') .change( function() {
        $('label').css('color', '#0f0');        
});
```

​
http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_/eCgyH/1/

Comment: Thanks Kyle, that seems to work, yet I have one more question. In terms of app optimization would you say that its better to use the javaScript that you've provided, or just make a global php if(thisPage !="my page with the problem"){load ezMark.js} and just not load the ezMark for that particular page. That works too.

Comment: It shouldn't really matter seeing as it's just two lines of code in one file, compared to another HTTP request just for that page. I'd keep it in the master js file which would be cached anyway.

Comment: @SantoshKhalse fixed :)

Answer (score 4):

This should work

```
<div class="ez-radio">
    <input type="radio" id="line0" name="line-style" value="1" class="ez-hide">
    <label>Label</label>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.ez-radio input:checked+label {
    font-size:2em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CGjCb/

Comment: @Ando I see lol Can you not disable the addon from loading on that page? How much control have you over the source? This should provide some insight http://www.itsalif.info/content/ezmark-jquery-checkbox-radiobutton-plugin

Comment: Yup, that is what I've done now, but I'm wondering if there is a better way to style the css by jumping over the `<div> since I'll have to make an if check every time i load a page and see check if that is the page where i don't want to load the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
// to apply only to checkbox use:
$('input[type="checkbox"]').not(".ez-hide").ezMark({
 checkboxCls: 'your-default-checkbox-class-name' ,
 checkedCls: 'your-checkbox-class-in-checked-state'
});
```